# Why does `(33).to_bytes(2, 'big')` return `b'\x00!'` instead of `b'\x00\x21'`?

Tags: python, python-3.2

I'm having a problem converting int to bytes in Python.

This works -

```
>>> (1024).to_bytes(2, 'big')
b'\x04\x00'
```

However this does not work as I would expect -

```
>>> (33).to_bytes(2, 'big')
b'\x00!'
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Note the exclamation mark in the second example. Look up its ASCII value.

Comment: You can force it display all the bytes in hexadecimal with `"".join("\\x{:02}".format(b) for b in (33).to_bytes(2, "big"))`.

Answer (score 9):

The decimal value `33` maps into the character `!` by the ASCII standard, so the interpreter can show it without using escape codes:

```
>>> b'\x21' * 3
b'!!!'
```

---

When printing a bytes object, python treats it as a sequence of characters (every character is saved as a byte, with each byte using normally a memory of 8 bits that maps into 2 hexadecimal digits value, e.g. `0x21 => 0b 0010 0001 => 33`), so values with corresponding printable ASCII characters are shown as their ASCII characters, and the rest are being represented by their hexadecimal values (in the format of `\xDD`).

Answer (score 3):

According to documentation -> https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html

```
 >>> (1024).to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
 b'\x04\x00'
 >>> (1024).to_bytes(10, byteorder='big')
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00'
 >>> (-1024).to_bytes(10, byteorder='big', signed=True)
 b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfc\x00'
 >>> x = 1000   
 >>> x.to_bytes((x.bit_length() // 8) + 1, byteorder='little')
 b'\xe8\x03'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not understanding that `!` is ASCII character 33, equivalent to `\x21`. This bytestring is exactly the bytestring you asked for; it just isn't displayed the way you were expecting.